# Port C# Code to Java

Tags: java, c#, pointers, struct, pointer-arithmetic

Following problem: I have a c# program doing some de/encryption in a very low level way. I used a tool, to convert most of the c# code to Java, which worked for most of the things but when it comes to such low level parts, the tool fails. The following data structure is used inside:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        private struct ByteUInt
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public byte Byte0;

            [FieldOffset(1)]
            public byte Byte1;

            [FieldOffset(2)]
            public byte Byte2;

            [FieldOffset(3)]
            public byte Byte3;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public uint FullUint;
        }
```

In the program, the bytes and the uint inside this struct are changed several times separately e.g. like this `MyByteUint.Byte0 &= someByte;` or `MyMyteUint.FullUint = someByte & 0x0F` or some other bitwise operations. Because the uint references the same memory as the 4 bytes, if i change one of them, the uint will change too and vice versa.

Since there are no real pointers in Java I don't know the best way to port such thing to Java, because i can not reference the memory directly. Is there any solution else than creating a class with getters and setters making fields private  and updating the uint/bytes when changing the other values?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: One thing to note is that bytes are signed in Java (-128 to 127), but not in C# (unless you use `sbyte`.)

Comment: Thanks for that info. In my case i think this is not a big problem because their bit representation should be the same.

Comment: May I ask you which tool did you use for the rest? Thanks!

Comment: @JoseManuelGomezAlvarez I believe it was [this one](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/csharp_to_java_converter_details.html) if I remember correctly. But I could be wrong, it's quite a long time since I tried that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the above struct is actually used to overlay (effectively) an array of bits as a `byte` array or an `int` array.

You can't do that in Java.  Your choices are:

- Model it as a `byte` array, and take the performance hit when you are doing indexed copying.
- Model it as an `int` array, and use bit shifting and masking to do the byte-wise operations.
- Use native code; i.e. code the encryption / decryption in C or C++ and use JNI or JNA or similar to call that code from Java.

You could also look at the `IntBuffer` or `ByteBuffer` classes.  These are (IMO) unlikely improve performance for your encryption / decryption operations taken in isolation, but when you combine them with NIO I/O (as an alternative to old-school I/O + copying to / from arrays) you may get better performance.

---

But it is also worth pointing out that this all has the smell of premature optimization.  I'd recommend writing the Java code the simplest way first, and worry about performance later .... if measurement tells you that it is a real concern.

Comment: Yes, this struct is used in the way you described it. I get a bit-stream as input with parts of it encrypted. The struct overlays this bits and is just a helper to do the necessary bit operations. Thanks for your answer, i will have a closer look at these options. Performance doesn't really mater for me. I just had the program already written in Java and the de/encryption algorithm in c# and i searched for an easy way to implement that in Java without changing the whole algorithm.

Comment: Well in that case, choose between a `byte[]` or a `int[]`.  You won't be "changing the whole algorithm" ... just rewriting or transforming bits of it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not "changing the algorithm". Sorry, english is not my native language, so i got difficulties in expressing the exact things i mean. I meant it like changing the architecture because the c# code has quiet a lot lines of code and i haven't got a lot of time. It's just some addition to a Java program for my studies :D

Comment: Just as an additional info, if anyone cares: The Java program reads some data from a radio signal receiver for radio controlled clocks and some weather forecast info's are also included in that data but they are encrypted. This was just a task for a subject at my university.